# K8s Ingress with AWS ALB Cluster IP and target-type: ip - not working?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, kubernetes-service

I was trying to create a alb load balancer with k8s ingress in aws. I have used the service as ClusterIP and changes the target-type in ingress to ip, but still its not working fine for me and the ingress service is not generating the load balancer address

This is my deployment file:
[deployment.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp42g.png)

This is my ingress file:
[ingress.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYG71.png)

This is the output when I run k8s get ingress command:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mge9.png)

can you please help me with this??

Please help me with this, and provide me a detail solution.

Answer (score 1):

ALB ingress controller not working with clusterIP.

- **Instance mode** work with Nodeport service. It return EC2 ip address as ALB target endpoint
- **IP mode** work with [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) (must install AWS CNI plugin for Kubernetes). It return Kubernetes Pod ip address as ALB target endpoint

In fact, we are using ClusterIP for Kubernetes internal connection, it does not need to expose any endpoint to external connection.

See the reference at [Kubernetes Ingress with AWS ALB Ingress Controller](https://aws.amazon.com/vi/blogs/opensource/kubernetes-ingress-aws-alb-ingress-controller/)

Comment: this is not true. AWS ALB ingress controller works with ClusterIP (alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip), at least with AWS VPC CNI. Probably it doesn't work with calico.

Comment: @gek [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) is a service with type ClusterIP without a private IP like normal ClusterIP. Traffic routed to pod dirrectly instead of kube proxy, that is the reason why AWS CNI is needed to provide pod IP address, which belong to VPC range